# Appcenter - Unable to install its profile on iPhone

Tags: ios, visual-studio-app-center

I am using AppCenter to sign and distribute iOS and Android builds.  All the people to whom I have sent the builds have been able to download and install the builds on their phones.

I can install the iOS build right from Xcode onto my iPhone using the same distribution certificate that I have used to sign the app on AppCenter.

However, when I do install the build from the AppCenter mail link, the build does install but it complains saying " Untrusted Enterprise Developer " on my iPhone.

When I checked under General -> Profiles -> XXX there is no profile for AppCenter.  Even if I try to register my device with AppCenter, I do see my device there but no profile is download/installed on my device.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks and Kind Regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 4):

I do not have a solution unfortunately. I only have notes about the many glitches of the AppCenter. I am unable to install the AppCenter profile on iPad.

- The AppCenter is neutered and barely able to do anything in non-Safari browsers. Frankly, the profile install process is doubly broken if you have the temerity to configure a non-Safari default browser. You will need to ensure the default browser is set to Safari for the duration of this process. That is requisite, but it is sadly not sufficient.
- The website warns you only once to enable mobile view. If you ever dismiss the warning, then it never reappears.
- Safari does not show a manual mobile or desktop view option in the context / share menu. To enable mobile view, you must go to the Safari section of the Settings app, and then Request Desktop Website -> All Websites -> Off. This allows the profile to download.
- Once downloaded, you navigate to a new section in the Settings app, in the General section. However, pressing Install merely loops back to the device list. The profile remains not installed.
- If you initiate the profile download from the light theme AppCenter page, then the crappy profile install process loop-lands on the light theme page. If you initiate the profile download from the other, potentially dark theme page, then it loop-lands on the dark theme page. There is evidently a lot of crazy URL redirection logic, which doesn't work at all.
- Rebooting iOS does not help. It actually resets the profile and you are back at having to redownload it.
- Microsoft closes reports of this bug as "cosmetic". Even though the bug prevents any and all AppCenter apps from running.

Sorry, I guess Microsoft and Apple don't care much for this system anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Built the app using an in-house provisioning profile solved this issue.